# Can we update a javascript array variable, with out reloading a page using ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Can we update a javascript array variable, with out reloading a page as well as with out refreshing? 
I am having a list of data in an array. Later I am getting some more data using php and ajax.
Now I would like to append the new data got from php ajax to the old javascript variable which is already having an array in it. I do not want to reload the page. But we can overwrite the data too. 
Using this javascript variable some javascript functions are getting exicuted and displayes some picture according to the data. Can we do something like that? or do we have to reload the frame to execute the javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**, you can add/append/concatenate/whatever new array items to an existing array.

Explanation: Assuming that you have a variable containing an array, and a response that is an array or contains an array, you can use the [`array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method to append the new content to the old array.

```
//let existingArray be your array in the page
var existingArray = [];

//during AJAX success, you overwrite the existing variable with
//a concatenated array comprising the old and the new.
existingArray = existingArray.concat(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I answer this question in terms of yes/no, then yeah, with ajax callback function returning the data will be appended/concatenated to js variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just like `AJAX`, where you need to call a JavaScript function for something to happen, you can also call a JavaScript function in the same way and instead of doing `AJAX` stuff, you can do other stuff. For instance add something to an array. Or overwrite it.

Simply call your function where you want it (in an `onclick`, or in the return of an `AJAX` call (success or error callbacks)), and let that function modify your variable.